# How to fix un-reliable date time calculations in PHP (non-database based)?

Tags: php, time

I am working on calculating date-times and converting them from the server time zone to a local timezone. I am noticing that using the same data the process does not return the same results. *(NB. I am not using values from a database. All calculations are based on the PHP server's time.)*

I cannot figure out how to make this work properly.

There are no error messages, just bad results.

In trying to do the calculations, i have used many var_dump()s to check the commands are working as desired. I have attempted to move the calculation outside of the conversion function, which also did not work.

The ultimate goal is to do a calculation where I get the date/time in my local timezone.

I have not found anything after three hours of searching online that could assist in this.

```php
defined('SYS_SES_TIMEOUT') or define('SYS_SES_TIMEOUT', 1800);

//Define New York Time Zone
$SYS_TIME_userTimezone=(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')); 

//DEFINE GMT Time Zone
$SYS_TIME_gmtTimezone=(new DateTimeZone('GMT')); 

//GET DateTime Objects in GMT and New YOrk Time Zones
$SYS_TIME_curDateTimeGMT = new DateTime(now,$SYS_TIME_gmtTimezone);
$SYS_TIME_curDateTime = new DateTime(now,$SYS_TIME_userTimezone);

//Define Offset from GMT Time. First calculate then assign to constant
$SYS_TIME_dateTime_offset = $SYS_TIME_userTimezone->getOffset($SYS_TIME_curDateTime);


function fSYS_TIME_ConvertToLocalTimeZone($time_to_convert, $timezone){
    if($time_to_convert instanceof DateTime){
        return new dateTime(strtotime($time_to_convert->getTimeStamp()),$timezone); 
    }
    else{
        return new dateTime(strtotime($time_to_convert),$timezone);
    }

}

function fSYS_TIME_ConvertTime_String_Long($time_to_format){
    return date_format($time_to_format,'D, F j, Y h:i A T e');
}

session_start();

//TESTS 
/** TEST A **/ var_dump(fSYS_TIME_ConvertToLocalTimeZone(($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] ),$SYS_TIME_userTimezone));
echo "<br />";
/** TEST B **/ var_dump(fSYS_TIME_ConvertToLocalTimeZone(($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] + SYS_SES_TIMEOUT),$SYS_TIME_userTimezone));
echo "<br />";
/** TEST C **/ 
var_dump((fSYS_TIME_ConvertToLocalTimeZone(($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] + SYS_SES_TIMEOUT),$SYS_TIME_userTimezone)) - (fSYS_TIME_ConvertToLocalTimeZone(($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] ),$SYS_TIME_userTimezone)));
echo "<br />";
/** TEST X **/ 
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] );
echo "<br />";
/** TEST Y **/ 
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] + SYS_SES_TIMEOUT);
echo "<br />";
/** TEST Z **/ 
var_dump(($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] + SYS_SES_TIMEOUT) - ($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']));
echo "<br />";
```

Using the 6 var_dump "test" statements that I have in my test code above. Tests X, Y and Z were done to look at the timestamp w/o conversion function.

### Tests A & X (Base Time)

**Test A** should be the server time adjusted to my current time (the server is in the Central US Time Zone while my location is Eastern (New York) US Time Zone). 
**Test X** shows this using the PHP integer representation of the time.

**Test A Output**: object(DateTime)#5 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-09-13 11:26:45.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" }

**Test X Output**: int(1568388405)

### Tests B & Y (Base Time + SYS_SES_TIMEOUT )

**Test B** should be 30 minutes more than TEST A from above. (The test does not show the adjusted time. 
I also tested doing the time adjustment outside of the call of the function as shown below, this did not change the results.

```php
$t12345 = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] + SYS_SES_TIMEOUT);
var_dump(fSYS_TIME_ConvertToLocalTimeZone($t12345,$SYS_TIME_userTimezone));
```

While **Test Y** shows this correctly when not using function.

**Test B Output**: object(DateTime)#5 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-09-13 11:26:45.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" }

**Test Y Output**: int(1568390205)

### Tests C & Z (Display difference in between B and A/Y and X)

Both Test C and Z should be equal to SYS_SES_TIMEOUT. However test C does not as Test B does increment.

**Test C Output**: int(0)

**Test Z Output**: int(1800)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue has to do with a misconception about the second argument to the `DateTime` constructor. The second arg  is not the timezone to convert to -- it's the timezone to interpret the first argument as *if it doesn't already contain a timezone*. I.e., if you do this:

```
new DateTime('2019-01-01 01:02:03', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

Then you get UTC. However, if the string already contains a timezone:

```
new DateTime('2019-01-01 01:02:03 EST', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

Then you'll get EST.

To convert to a different timezone, just use the `setTimezone()` method:

```
(new DateTime($timeString))->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

To cover all the bases, you'll want to put both together:

```
(new DateTime($timeString, new DateTimeZone('UTC')))->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

I.e., if $timestring doesn't contain a timezone, then interpret it as if it were UTC -- and if $timeString does contain a timezone, then explicitly convert it to UTC. (Or whatever your target is.)

[Edit]

Integer timestamps are always UTC. If you want to push it forward by 30 minutes, just add the number of seconds to the integer. The DateTime constructor recognizes integer timestamps if you prefix them with `@`. If you want that new timestamp to be represented in a different timezone, you must call setTimezone().

```
$timestamp = 1568395623;
$new = new DateTime('@' . ($timestamp + 1800));
$new->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York));
print_r($new);
```

Yields:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-09-13 13:57:03.000000 // <= 30 minutes after $timestamp
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/New_York
)
```

Comment: The problem that I was having is that all of the posts and answers that I have found use strings IE 2019-01-01 01:02:03 for the date. The value that I am working with is the timestamp so its an integer. (1568394769). What I need to do is (1) get 30 minutes later and (2) get output to display it in the format 'D, F j, Y h:i A T e'

Comment: When I was first working on the code I had used
```php
$SYS_TIME_curDateTimeGMT = new DateTime(now,$SYS_TIME_gmtTimezone);
$SYS_TIME_curDateTime = new DateTime(now,$SYS_TIME_userTimezone);

$SYS_TIME_curDateTime_Format_String_Long =date_format($SYS_TIME_curDateTime,'D, F j, Y h:i A T e');
$SYS_TIME_curDateTimeGMT_Format_String_Long =date_format($SYS_TIME_curDateTimeGMT,'D, F j, Y h:i A T e');
``` 
when I echo'd the String_Long variables, I got the original which was in GMT and then the same time but in EDT.

Comment: Thanks! that explains it a lot better.